# Universal Windows Application Client/Server Data Access

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal

In a Universal Windows App, how would I access data from a company database? Web Service seems the only way that I have seen so far. Somehow I need to hook into the company database.

This particular app will run in a shop shipping area (desktop) and in trucking (mobile/tablet) when they deliver or drop off.

So we were thinking when trucking gets into the wifi range to the shops, then It can connect to the sql server database somehow.

Comment: for the folks that have the power to down vote, you should also offer a useful suggestion or answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is an option... another option could be configure an public port to access your database (configure db instance, firewall, server and route too) and your app can connect with database from any place. Or use WebAPI to connect with database with basic services.... or design a webapp and public it.

Do not leave aside the security of the data.

Answer (score -1):

You cant connect to sql servers via network. To have a local cache / database have a look at sqlite. This can be embedded in your app

Also have a look to azure app services with offline data sync (weird name but oke..)
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync this can give you a headstart for what you are looking for